# Click a element On Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, keypress

there I am working on a project for the login form.
I need to write a code that when the user pressed Enter on the Keyboard in input X code Call the function Y.
I saw Many Pages on Stackoverflow but theirs not working for me. I use Jquery In my project.

```
<div class="main">
   <h2 class="title"><br> Wikipedia Image Finder!</h2>
   <div class="form">
      <label class="S_label" for="input_data">             <span class="Label_text">Image Title:</span>         </label>         
      <div class="ll">
         <input name="input" type="text" maxlength="999" id="input_data" minlength="1" placeholder="Query to Search" required>       
         <div class="img_btn" id="submit_div""></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share some code you tried.

Comment: You should modify the question so that the code is displayed there, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code.

```js
$("input").keyup(function(event){
        // checking the pressed key is Enter
    if(event.which == 13) {
       search(event.target.value);
    }
});

function search(text){
    alert('called search with '+ text)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">     <h2 class="title"><br> Wikipedia Image Finder!</h2>     <div class="form">         <label class="S_label" for="input_data">             <span class="Label_text">Image Title:</span>         </label>         <div class="ll">       <input name="input" type="text" maxlength="999" id="input_data" minlength="1" placeholder="Query to Search" required>       <div class="img_btn" id="submit_div""></div>         </div></div> </div>
```